# MySQL Join and newest lot information

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-by, having

I have four tables. The first describing a mix of items. The second is a linking table between the mix, and the items. The third is the item table, and the fourth holds lot information - lot number, and when that lot starts being used.

**mix**

```
mixID | mixName
----------------
1     | Foxtrot
2     | Romeo
```

**mixLink**

```
mixID | itemID
----------------
1     | 1
1     | 2
1     | 3
```

**item**

```
itemID| itemName
----------------
1     | square
2     | triangle
3     | hexagon
```

**itemLots**

```
itemID| lotNo | startDate
-------------------------
1     | 22/5/3| 22/07/16
2     | 03/5  | 25/07/16
2     | 04/19 | 12/08/16
3     | 15/0  | 05/08/16
```

Now, I need to be able to fetch the information from the database, which details all the items from a mix, as well as the most recently used lot number, something like this:

```
itemName | lotNo
----------------
square   | 22/5/3
triangle | 04/19
hexagon  | 15/0
```

I've tried a dozen different mixes of joins, group by's, maxes, subqueries, and havings; all to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated, I've been pulling my hair out for hours, and I feel like my fingernails are just scraping at the solution!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql inner join max](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336064/mysql-inner-join-max)

Comment: And dates are stored using a date data type?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the result you're after and will perform pretty well if you have your indexes done properly. I'm not sure how you're meaning to reference `mix` as it's not apparent in your sample output but I've included it in the `WHERE` clause so hopefully you can understand where you would use it.

```
SELECT i.itemName
, (SELECT il.lotNo FROM itemLots il 
WHERE il.itemID=i.itemID
ORDER BY il.startDate desc
LIMIT 1) as lotNo
FROM item i 
JOIN mixLink ml ON ml.itemID=i.itemID
JOIN mix m ON m.mixID=ml.mixID
WHERE m.mixName="Foxtrot";
```

Comment: Also, this is assuming you don't actually need to do a `JOIN`, which is a common mistake to make